# Cannot read properties of undefined typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically I have two components, one is a parent and the other is a child, But the communication between them does not work, even though I import the information correctly(I hope)

this is my shipper-form.component.html:

```
<p>add a shipper here!</p>
```

this is shipper.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import { untilDestroyed } from "@ngneat/until-destroy";

import { select, Store } from "@ngrx/store";

import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
import { BciDetailsComponent } from 'src/app/shared/components';

import { ColumnDef } from "src/app/shared/models/bci-table.models";
import { QueryConfig } from "src/app/shared/models/query-config.model";
import { ShipperFormComponent } from "./components/shipper-form/shipper-form.component";

import { Shipper } from "./models/shipper.model";

import { loadShippers } from "./store/actions/shippers.actions";

import * as fromShippers from './store/reducers/shippers.reducers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shipper',
  templateUrl: './shippers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shippers.component.scss']
})

export class ShipperComponent implements OnInit{

@ViewChild(ShipperFormComponent) shipperForm: ShipperFormComponent;

  constructor(
    
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
   }


  addShipper()
  {
    this.shipperForm.asdf();
}
```

And my shipper-form.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Shipper } from '../../models/shipper.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shipper-form',
  templateUrl: './shipper-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shipper-form.component.scss']
})
export class ShipperFormComponent implements OnInit {
  shipperForm: FormGroup;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shipperForm = new FormGroup({
      shipperId: new FormControl(''),
      companyName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    })
  }

  reset() {
    this.shipperForm.reset();
  }

  asdf()
  {
    console.log('123123123');
  }

}
```

In my shipper.module.ts I have the imports:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ShipperComponent,
    ShipperFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ShipperRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(fromShippers.shippersFeatureKey, fromShippers.reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ShippersEffects])
  ]
})

export class ShipperModule{

}
```

But i get an error when I try to call the asdf() function which should display 123123123. The error says: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asdf')" and then some stack trace.

Comment: I'm curious to know when addShipper() is called. It could be that the shipper component isn't done creating the view, that would mean that @ViewChild(ShipperFormComponent) shipperForm will still be undefined

Comment: Can you add the code for the `shipper.component.html`?
As @Makaku00 already mentioned we do need some more information. If you render the  shipper-form directly in the shipper it should work as long as `addShipper` is called after the view is initialized (e.g. in `ngAfterViewInit` or on click). It does not work before that (e.g. `ngOnInit`) or if the component is not visible (e.g. `ngIf`)